# CComBSTR memory leak and assignment

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, com

I am debugging some old c++/COM code without having very much COM experience.

1. Is it correct that the code below will leak (the empty string is lost)?
2. Is is even correct and safe to assign the value of cText to myCComBstr in this way?

Code:

```
TCHAR cText[MAX_PATH] = {0};
CComBSTR myCComBstr(L"");
functionThatFillsDataInTextBuffer(&cText[0]);
myCComBstr = cText;  // the empty string is leaked?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign the array to CComBSTR it will free what it previously was holding, you can always look in the header to see how things are implemented:

```
CComBSTR& operator=(_In_opt_z_ LPCOLESTR pSrc)
{
  if (pSrc != m_str)
  {
    ::SysFreeString(m_str);
    if (pSrc != NULL)
    {
      m_str = ::SysAllocString(pSrc);
      if (!*this)
      {
         AtlThrow(E_OUTOFMEMORY);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      m_str = NULL;
    }
  }
  return *this;
}
```